# How can I make a paragraph inside itemize in Latex?

Tags: paragraphs

Hi all I have this code that is not working

```
\begin{itemize}
\item\textbf{\large Deliverable}
    \par Pargraph 1. \par
    Paragraph 2 \par
    Paragraph 3.  
\end{itemize}
```

I would like to obtain the classical Latex indentation when paragraphing:

```
Par1 write part
write paragraph 1
  Par2 write part
write paragraph 2
  Par3 write part
write paragraph 3
```

Comment: @modnar no it is correct on overleaf code is compiling

Comment: Please show a minimal compilable example (starting with, e.g., \documentclass{article}) and ending at \end{document}) for your question.

Comment: you never need to use `\par` in a document, simply use a blank line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{
  listparindent=\parindent,
  parsep=0pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item\textbf{\large Deliverable}
  Paragraph 1. \lipsum[1]

  Paragraph 2. \lipsum[1]

  Paragraph 3. \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]